# Laravel: How to compare execution time between Query Builder and Eloquent

Tags: laravel

I have three sets of data, or models: **Red**, **Blue** and **Green**. All are linked with Many-To-Many relationships (and pivot tables).

In the two ways below, for a given **Red** id `$blue_id = 123` and given **Blue** ids...

```
$blue_id = 123;
$blue_ids = [2, 3, 5];
```

...I'm getting the list of all **Green** ids for, either directly or through the `Blue` model.

```
red -> greens
red -> blue -> greens
```

#### First way:

```
$green_ids = Green::whereHas('reds', function ($q) use ($red_id) {
    $q->where('reds.id', $red);
})->orWhereHas('blues', function ($q) use ($blue_ids) {
    $q->whereIn('blues.id', $blues);
})->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

#### Second way:

```
$green1 = DB::table('red_green')->where('red_id', $user->red_id)->pluck('green_id')->toArray();
$green2 = DB::table('green_blue')->whereIn('blue_id', $blues)->pluck('green_id')->toArray();
$green_ids = array_merge($green1, $green2);
```

Which one of the two ways below has the best execution time and how to know it ?

Comment: Use that https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar, It will tell you execution time and the number of queries run with eloquent.

Comment: This has nothing to do with eloquent and query builder. In essence it just has to do with whether two distinct queries are better than a a single query with those two queries as nested subqueries. Either way it should be easy to  determine which is faster via various means like getting the time it takes to get the result to running the actual underlying queries in the SQL console and seeing how much time it takes

Answer (score 1):

The best way is the first one, as it runs purely on the DB, the second way executes more queries and then it handles 2 arrays in memory, the first way just once, you can know more in the first way by removing `pluck` and `toArray` and replace it with `toSql()` so you can see the query it want to execute.

Comment: Thanks! Very useful method!

Answer (score 0):

I finally got my answer by adding this to the `boot()` method of `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`:

```
DB::listen(function ($query) {
    Log::info($query->sql);
    Log::info($query->bindings);
    Log::info($query->time);
});
```

*ref*. [Laravel: Listening For Query Events](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#listening-for-query-events)

But it's actually difficult to see which one has better execution time. I'm checking the first way with `php artisan tinker`, exiting, doing `php artisan optimize:clear`, re-opening `tinker` check the second way, but I always get different execution times where both may show to be the fastest.